# How to pass an element of arrayList object from one arraylist to another?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to pass an element from an object in the an ArrayList such as SupplierID from the Supplier ArrayList to Product ArrayList where SupplierID in ProductID list is the SupplierID from Supplier List. The inputs are given by the user.

Here is my Supplier code:

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Supplier {
    private String s_SupplierID;
    private String s_ContactName;
    private String s_Company;
    private String s_Email;
    private String s_Phone;

    ArrayList<Supplier> spl = new ArrayList<Supplier>();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Supplier()
    {

    }
    public Supplier (String s_SupplierID, String s_ContactName, String s_Company, String s_Email, String Phone){

        this.s_SupplierID = s_SupplierID;
        this.s_ContactName = s_ContactName;
        this.s_Company = s_Company;
        this.s_Email = s_Email;
        this.s_Phone = Phone;

    }

    public void addSupplier(){
        System.out.println("Please Enter Supplier ID: ");
        String ID = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please Enter Name: ");
        String Name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Company Name: ");
        String Company = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Email: ");
        String Email = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Phone: ");
        String Phone = keyboard.nextLine();
        spl.add(new Supplier(ID,Name,Company,Email,Phone));




    }
```

Here is my Product code:

```
package main;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Product{
    private String p_ProductID;
    private String p_Name;
    private int p_SerialNum;
    private double p_Price;
    private int p_Quantity;
    private Supplier p_Supplier;
    private int p_ExpiryDate;
    private double p_Discount;
    private double p_BulkDiscount;
    private String p_SupplierID;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Product> ppl = new ArrayList<Product>();

    public Product(){

    }

    public Product(Supplier s,String p_ProductID, String p_Name, int p_SerialNum, double p_Price, int p_Quantity, double p_Discount, double p_BulkDiscount){
        p_Supplier = s;
        this.p_ProductID = p_ProductID;
        this.p_Name = p_Name;
        this.p_SerialNum = p_SerialNum;
        this.p_Price = p_Price;
        this.p_Quantity = p_Quantity;   
        this.p_SupplierID = p_Supplier.getSupplierID();
        this.p_Discount = p_Discount;
        this.p_BulkDiscount = p_BulkDiscount;

    }

    public Product(String p_ProductID, String p_Name, int p_SerialNum, double p_Price, double p_Discount, double p_BulkDiscount){

        this.p_ProductID = p_ProductID;
        this.p_Name = p_Name;
        this.p_SerialNum = p_SerialNum;
        this.p_Price = p_Price; 
        this.p_SupplierID = p_Supplier.getSupplierID();
        this.p_Discount = p_Discount;
        this.p_BulkDiscount = p_BulkDiscount;

    }

    public void addProduct(){

        System.out.println("Please Enter ProductID: ");
        String ID = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Product Name: ");
        String Name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Product Serial Number: ");
        int SerialNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Product Price: ");
        Double Price = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Product Discount: ");
        Double Discount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Product Bulk Discount: ");
        Double BulkDiscount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        ppl.add(new Product( ID,Name,SerialNum, Price, Discount, BulkDiscount));

}
```

Here is my main method to run it:  *UPDATE*

package main;

```
import java.util.*;



public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) { // testing add/update/remove on supplier
        //ArrayList<Supplier> spl = new ArrayList<Supplier>();
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Supplier id?");
        //Supplier.s_SupplierID = scan.nextInt();
        Supplier s = new Supplier();
        Product p = new Product();

        s.addSupplier();
        p.addProduct();
}
```

As the Supplier constructor creates a Supplier that includes SupplierID, ContactName, Company, Email and phone, I would like to pass this SupplierID over to the SupplierID field in the Product Constructor when adding a new product. The result i would like to achieve is to assign SupplierID to the products added right after a Supplier has been added. How do i do this? Thanks.

Comment: Wait...your `Supplier` class has a list of suppliers?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, i am fairly new to java and object oriented programming, would it be better if its in the main.java class?

Comment: If you ever want it to execute, you'll need a main method.

Comment: You never actually showed us the code which is using `Product` and `Supplier`.

Comment: Make one more java file that will first create a supplier list and then pass those id in Product contructor

Comment: @gonephishing So i should also be creating the product list in that same class as well?

Comment: @DarioOngsono Most likely. With your current design, every instance of Supplier will have its own list of suppliers and every instance of Product will have its own list of products.